# How to convert ndarray to integer in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I have a code where I have 5 `ndarray` and I need to visualize it on a `matplotlib.` To start with, I am just trying to plot only one `ndarray` like below:

```
x = data['embeddings'][0]
y = np.linspace(0, 50, 128)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

It looks like something below:

[image]

Now the problem here is that if I plot other 4 ndarray's as well, this graph will look very messy and I will not be able check which ndarray is which one. So I was wondering if there is any way we can convert or map `ndarray` to `int` so that when we display it, there is only one point drawn on graph for one `ndarray`. Please suggest some good solution. Thanks

Comment: One trivial solution is assign color to each array. If that looks like too messy and crowded, maybe try to use [`pandas.DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) on each array before you plot it. It would be important to know what do the values actually represent to give a better suggestion.

Comment: @PéterLeéh Can you give a very quick example

Comment: Try looking at the [matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/gallery/index.html) and elsewhere for different types of plots that might be helpful to you.  We would need to know much more about your data than we do to answer this type of question without wild guesses.  There might also be a way to reduce the dimensionality of your data (like what you might be suggesting by "converting to int"), but, again, we'd need to know more.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to distinguish between the data drawn for all the nd array, you can use label alongwith legend.

```
x = data['embeddings'][0]
y = np.linspace(0, 50, 128)
plt.scatter(x, y, label="FirstGraph")

x2 = ....
y2= ....
plt.scatter(x2, y2, label="SecondGraph")
plt.legend() 
plt.show()
```

By this way, you will be able to distinguish the data drawn for different nd arrays.

Comment: Yes I think this can also help. Thanks